# How to handle dictionary keys that do not exist in a loop?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, jsonparser

I tried to parse json and use for loop in Python.
`obj` is json and as you know it is like dictionary in list in dictionary in dictionary...and so on.

So I parse json and make it as a `for` loop like this:

```
all = obj['products']
for a in obj:
      recommendSellerScore.append(a['recommendSellerScore'])
```

However, the problem is `'recommendSellerScore'` which is key does not exist in some lists.

What I want as a result is to print `'None'` where `recommendSellerScore` does not exist, and print values where `recommendSellerScore` does exist.

```
for a in all:
    if a['recommendSellerScore'] in all:
        recommendSellerScore.append(a['recommendSellerScore'])
    else:
        continue
        print('None')
```

I ran this code above, but got an Error because `'recommendSellerScore'` does not exist.

```
for a in all:
    if ['recommendSellerScore'] in all:
        recommendSellerScore.append(a['recommendSellerScore'])
    else:
        continue
        print('None')
```

This one worked, however, since `'recommendSellerScore'` exists in list in dictionary, it was not iterable. (I guess)

Please fix my code, and any comments or advice will be appreciated!

Comment: @hitter thanks for your answer. May I know how I can upvote on comments? Only I can see is a flag on comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is fixed version of your code (I took out the `continue` statement and the `[]` around the string):

```
for a in all:
    if "recommendSellerScore" in a:
        recommendSellerScore.append(a["recommendSellerScore"])
    else:
        print("None")
```

Comment: Don't use `"something" in a` because it might not work as intended if "something" is found in the values. `"something" in a.keys()` is much safer and explicit.

Comment: @Guimoute you are wrong,`"something" in a` is the same with `"something" in a.keys()`

Comment: this is the best answer so far  ;)

Comment: @kederrac My bad, I mixed up with `dictview`s. Still a good idea to check explicitly for keys or values.

Comment: @Guimoute Thank you for your advice! It worked with ".keys()". 

The code that I use as a result is:

for a in all:
    if "recommendSellerScore" in a.keys():
        recommendSellerScore.append(a["recommendSellerScore"])
    else:
        recommendSellerScore.append("None")

Comment: @kederrac I don't know why, I may be missing something in the explanation, however it only works with "something" in a.keys().
Anyway thank you for your comment also! :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like the code below works for you?

```
for a in all:
    if a.get(['recommendSellerScore']) is not None:
        recommendSellerScore.append(a['recommendSellerScore'])
  else:
      print("None")
      # No need for continue here.
```

Comment: you can't have lists as key in a dict, your code should raise : `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: also you can't use `dict.get` with a list

Comment: The OP said that the `obj` is json -> therefore translated to a dictionary, after json loads

Comment: look at your first comment you are considering `a` as a dict

Answer (score 2):

You can use `get` method of dictionaries to try to access the dictionary value, if the key is not present you can provide a default value, if you don't specify one, it will output `None`, for example:

```py
key = 'recommendSellerScore'
a = [{key: 1}, {}]

recommendSellerScore = []
for d in a:
    score = d.get(key)
    if score is not None:
        print(score)
        recommendSellerScore.append(score)
    else:
        print('None')
```

Edit: as pointed by @kederrac if your data can have `{key: None}` values and you are interested in keeping those `None` values then it's best to ask if the key is truly present in the dictionary, for example:

```py
key = 'recommendSellerScore'
a = [{key: 1}, {key: None}]

recommendSellerScore = []
for d in a:
    if key in d.keys():
        print(d[key])
        recommendSellerScore.append(d[key])
    else:
        print('None')
```

It will print:

```
>>> 1
>>> None
```

Comment: what if   `a = [{key: None}, {}]` ? your code will fail to store in `recommendSellerScore` the `None` value

Comment: @kederrac, true, in that case, see `Edit`.

Comment: if you have `a = [{key: 1}, {key: None}, {1:1}]` ?